# How to make expanded rows in react-virtualized correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-virtualized, virtualscroll

Why scroll is jumping?

I made the smallest window size (by making console bigger)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-expandable-row-forked-9kgmu5?file=/src/Component.js

I tried:

```
this._listRef.forceUpdateGrid() // Rerender list with new size
```

But it didn't help.

Also what if there will be not one expanded row, but an array of expanded rows? Is rowRenderer ok for this case? I thought to make details inside row component and make height of the row bigger when it's expanded. Total height of data computed dynamically correctly, I know how to do it. But when some elements deleted from DOM by library, empty space appears after elements that left in the DOM. Why could this be? How to do this correctly?

Comment: Try this article https://blog.logrocket.com/rendering-large-lists-react-virtualized/#calculating-height-row-automatically